How to prove surjectivity? If $\mathcal{A}$ is an alphabet, then the set $W$ of all words from $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.
I'm trying to prove that  If $\mathcal{A}$ is an alphabet, then the set $W$ of all words from $\mathcal{A}$  is countable.
In resume I'm kind of using the Gödel enumeration. I index all symbols from $\mathcal{A}$ with a function $I : \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$. In the other hand, as I'm defining $W$ like:
$$W = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}W_k$$
Where $W_n = \mathcal{A}^n$ the cross product of $\mathcal{A}$ with itself $n$ times. Then $\forall x \in W \ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in W_n$. Then we can see all words as n-tuples, i.e. $x = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ where $x_i \in \mathcal{A} \ \forall i \in \{1 ,... ,n\}$.
Then, I'm defining $\forall x \in W$ the function  $p:x \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}$, with $\mathcal{P}$ the set of all prime numbers, where $p$ assigns   the $i$-prime to the $i$-symbol in x. For example $p(x_3) ="\text{the third prime}" = 5$ and $x_3$ is a symbol in the alphabet in the third position of the word.
Then I define the function $\varphi$ as:
\begin{align*}
\varphi:W &\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
        x &\longmapsto \varphi(x)
\end{align*}
$$\text{Where } \varphi(x) =\varphi(x_1, ..., x_n) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}p(x_i)^{I(x_i)} = p(x_1)^{I(x_1)} ... p(x_n)^{I(x_n)} = p_1^{I(x_1)} ... p_n^{I(x_n)}  $$
Now, inyectivity is easy considering the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. But i dont know how to proceed with surjectivity. I have to prove that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists x \in W$ such that $N = \varphi(x)$

If your alphabet is finite then $\varphi$ is not surjective, e.g. its image does not contain arbitrarily large primes. But 1) you don't need surjectivity, you can use the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem instead, and 2) it is much easier than this. You can write down a bijection by listing the words in lexicographic order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order

But if it is not surjective, then it is not inyective from $\mathbb{N}$ to $W$, right? I cannot use  Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem or should I use another function?

I don't know what you mean. $\varphi$ is injective but not surjective. If you can't use CBS then, again, you can write down a very elementary bijection using lexicographic order (if $A$ is finite). The details are on Wikipedia but I can also write something if that would be helpful.

well, I can see the bijection in $\varphi$ for the case when $A$ is infinite. But I don´t understand entirely the bijection through lexicographic order. it'd be very helpful if you write something about it. Thank you.

Consider the alphabet ${a,b}$. Then one bijection would be $a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,aaa,\dots$. The same idea generalizes to any size alphabet.

Maybe I have a kind of constructive spirit, How can I explicitly define the lexicographical function? I only need to prove inyectivity from $\mathbb{N}$ to $W$, as I already have $\varphi$ inyectivity from $W$ to $\mathbb{N}$, with CBS theorem I'd have bijection.

if $A = {a,b}$ then $\varphi(ab) = 2 ^1 3^2 = 18$ $\varphi(ba) = 2 ^2 3^1 = 12$ and $18 \not = 12$

Oh, sorry again, it seems I quite misread your definition.

no problem. the words are n-tuples so $ab = (a,b)$ and $ba = (b,a)$ both have not the same entries.  Also, even if the alphabet is weird like  $A = {a, aa}$ then the words $(a,aa)$ and $(aa,a)$ are not the same, though without tuple notation they look the same as $aaa$

If $\mathcal{A}$ is finite then $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\mathcal{A}| = m$. By definition of $W$ as $$W = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}W_k$$ where $W_k = \mathcal{A}^k$ y $W_0 = \{\varepsilon\}$.
Then $|W_k| = |\mathcal{A}^k| = m^k \ \forall k > 0.$
If $m = 1$ then the alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ has one single symbol, then $|W_k| = 1 \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. i.e. There's only one word of length $k \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. By this fact we can propose the function $\textit{length of a word}$ $|\cdot|: W \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as a b ijective function. It is inyective because if we take $|x|, |y| \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x| = |y| = n$, and as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ |W_n| = 1$ and $x,y \in W_n$ , i.e. there's only one word in $W_n$, necessarily $x = y$ . It is also surjective  because as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists W_n$ such that $|W_n| = 1$ then $x \in W_n$ is the only word such that $|x|=n$.
Now, when $m > 1$ let's follow the next analysis to enumerate the words in $W$. In one hand we know that $\forall x \in W \ \exists j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in W_j$. Then we can propose $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$ an injective function $I : W_j \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that indexes the words in $W_j$ where $1 \leq I(x) \leq m^j$ because there are $|W_j| = |\mathcal{A}^j| = m ^j$ words in $W_j$. Then we can define $x_{ij} : = \textit{''the i'th word in $W_j$''} \ \ \forall x \in W$  where $i = I(x)$ with $x \in W_j$. Remark the fact that $1\leq i\leq m^j$.
Remark that before the first word in the set $W_j$ $\forall j > 0$, i.e. $x_{1j}$, there are $$\sum_{k =1}^{j-1}|W_k| = \sum_{k =1}^{j-1}|A^k| = \sum_{k =1}^{j-1}m^k = \frac{m(m^{j-1}-1)}{m-1}$$ words. Thus we can propose the following function $\varphi$ that assigns a single natural number to each word in $W$:
\begin{align*}
    \varphi : W &\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
              x &\longmapsto \varphi (x) 
\end{align*}
$$\text{Where } \varphi (x_{1,0}) = \varphi (\varepsilon) = 0$$ $$and $$
$$\varphi (x) = \varphi (x_{ij}) = \sum_{k =1}^{j-1}m^k + I(x) = \frac{m(m^{j-1}-1)}{m-1} +i \ \ \ \ \forall j > 0$$
Remark that $\varphi$ is bijective:
Let's prove injectivity:
Let be $\varphi(x), \varphi(y) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(x)= \varphi(y)$. If $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y) = 0$, by definition of $\varphi$ then  $x = y = \varepsilon$. In the case when $\varphi(x), \varphi(y) >0$ we have that $\exists a,b,p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in W_b$, $y \in W_q$, $I(x) = a$ and $I(y) = p$ where $0<a\le m^b$ y $0<p\le m^q$, then:
\begin{align}
  \varphi(x_{ab}) &= \varphi(y_{pq})\\
  \frac{m(m^{b-1}-1)}{m-1} + a &= \frac{m(m^{q-1}-1)}{m-1} + p\\
  m(m^{b-1}-1) + a(m-1) &= m(m^{q-1}-1) + p(m-1) \\
  m^b-m + a(m-1) &= m^q-m + p(m-1) \\
  m^b + a(m-1) &= m^q + p(m-1) \tag{*}
\end{align}
We must prove that $a =p$ and $b = q$. Let's proceed by contradiction.
Suppose that $a \not=p$ y $b \not= q$. i.e. without loss of generality $(a >p$ y $b > q)$ or $(a >p$ y $b < q)$.
In the case when $a >p$ and $b > q$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
 a(m-1) > p(m-1) \tag{1}   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    m^b > m^q \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Summing (1) and (2):
$$\therefore \ m^b + a(m-1) > m^q + p(m-1) \ \ \unicode{x21af} $$
This is a contradiction to equation (*).
Analogously we get to a similar contradiction when assuming $a <p$ and $b < q$.
In the case when $a >p$ and $q > b$, as $a \leq m^b$ and $p >0$, then
\begin{equation}
a-p < m^b  \tag{3}   
\end{equation}
In the other hand, as $b < q$ then $0 < q - b$
i.e. $1\le q - b$. Thus, we have that  $m \le m^{q-b}$, and therefore:
\begin{equation}
     m-1 \le m^{q-b}-1 \tag{4}
\end{equation}
This way, by (3) and (4) we have:
\begin{align*}
    (a-p)(m-1) &< m^b(m^{q-b}-1) \\
    a(m-1) -p(m-1) &< m^q - m^b\\
    m^b+a(m-1) &< m^q+p(m-1) \ \ \unicode{x21af}
\end{align*}
This contradicts equation (*). Analogously we get a similar contradiction assuming $p >a$ y $b > q$.
Therefore, necessarily $a = p$ and $b = q$. Thus $x_{ab} = y_{pq}$. i.e. $x = y$. $$\therefore \ \varphi \ \text{is injective.}$$
Let's prove surjectivity:
Let be $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and be $t = \text{max}\{ \frac{m(m^k-1)}{m-1}< N : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, i.e. $t$ is the greatest number less than N in the sequence $\{ \frac{m(m^k-1)}{m-1}\}_{ k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Thus $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t =\frac{m(m^k-1)}{m-1}$ where $t < N$, therefore $$k = \log_{m}(\frac{t(m-1)}{m} + 1)$$
Remark that $t$ and $k$ depends of $N$, i.e. $t = t(N)$ and $k = k(N)$. If we do  $i = N - t$ and $j = k + 1$, by the analysis in the construction of $\varphi$ we get that $x_{ij}$ is $\textit{the $i$'th word in the set $W_j$}$. Therefore $\forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists x \in W$ such that $\varphi(x) = N$. $$\therefore \ \varphi \ \text{is surjective}$$ $$\therefore \ \varphi \ \text{is bijective}$$ $$\therefore \ \text{ If $\mathcal{A}$ is finite then $W$ is countable}.$$
$$\blacksquare$$

I am of the opinion that countability arguments should be made as simple as possible. The following general observation does it:

Claim: A countable disjoint union $X = \bigsqcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} X_k$ of non-empty finite sets $X_k$ is countable.

Sketch. To see this let's really think about what a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \cong X$ is. It is the same as a list of the elements of $X$, namely $f(1)$ is the first element of the list, $f(2)$ is the second element of the list, and so forth. So, any way of writing the elements of a set in an infinite list, in such a way that every element appears exactly once, constitutes a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.
Now we can list the elements of $X$ by first listing the elements of $X_0$ in any order, then listing the elements of $X_1$ in any order, then listing the elements of $X_2$ in any order, and so forth. $\Box$
This can be made completely precise but it's notationally tedious to write out exactly what the bijection is, you have to write it in terms of the exact cardinalities of the sets $X_k$ and so forth. But the idea should be clear, we are just writing down a list, and the important thing is to understand the idea.
To apply the claim we let $X_k = W_k$ be the set of all words of length $k$ (assuming the alphabet $A$ is finite). For example let's take $A = \{ a, b \}$ to be an alphabet of size $2$. We can write down a list of all words by first writing down the words of length $0$ in any order: there's exactly one, the empty word. Then the words of length $1$ in any order: say $a, b$. Then the words of length $2$ in any order: say $bb, ba, aa, ab$ (just to emphasize that it really does not matter what the order is). Then the words of length $3$ in any order... so an example of such a list begins
$$\varepsilon, a, b, bb, ba, aa, ab, bab, bba, \dots $$
We can also pick a specific order to list the words $W_k$ of length $k$ in using lexicographic order. (This lets us avoid what is, strictly speaking, a use of countable choice in the above argument.) This is a fancy way of referring to a generalization of dictionary order: we pick a total order on the alphabet $A$, and then we order words of a fixed length according to the first letter, then the second letter if the first letter is the same, then the third letter if the first two letters are the same, etc.
Again this is notationally tedious to write out explicitly. Here is an example with an alphabet $\{ a, b, c \}$ of size $3$, with the usual dictionary order in which $a$ comes first, then $b$, then $c$. So the list of words of length $1$ in lexicographic order is
$$a, b, c,$$
the list of words of length $2$ in lexicographic order is
$$aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc,$$
the list of words of length $3$ in lexicographic order begins
$$aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, \dots $$
and so forth. If you want to make all of this fully explicit then I encourage you to try it as an exercise.
Another way to think about lexicographic order is that you can pick the alphabet $A = \{ 0, 1, \dots b-1 \}$ and then words can be interpreted as base-$b$ expansions of natural numbers, which inherit an ordering from $\mathbb{N}$. This is almost but not quite a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ because we keep track of leading zeroes (so it is surjective but not injective). So for example, identifying $a = 0, b = 1, c = 2$, we get $0, 1, 2, 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 000, 001, \dots$ which can be interpreted as base-$3$ expansions.

I think I have a solution. I'll post during the day.

I added a tedious constructive solution below. Thank you very much for your replies and insights.
